# How can I add multiple timezones to Freya?

Tags: release-freya, clock

I'm trying to have multiple timezones displayed when clicking on the clock, a behavior available in Luna but missing in Freya. After several months I still didn't see this option added back. Is there any way to make it work, or a workaround to see multiple timezones?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a has been filed about that (https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1369233). It seems like you cannot have multiple timezones, not in this version of elementary. Maybe you could try with some custom indicators or third-party applications ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. Install `dconf-editor`

You will need to install `dconf-editor`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

### 2. Set your Locations

Once installed,  go to `com.canonical.indicator.datetime` and look for `locations` variable and add your desired locations, separated with commas, and between ' '.

They should look something like these:

```
['America/Los_Angeles Los Angeles', 'America/New_York New York', 'Europe/London London', 'Europe/Paris Paris', 'Asia/Tokyo Tokyo']
```

If you don't know timezone names, you can go to:

[TZ database- Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

### 3. Enable Locations

Click on `show-locations` checkbox. To disable, you can simply uncheck this option.

Comment: Perfect! This worked beautifully and on real time, no logoff needed.

Answer (score 7):

## In the Terminal

**Set the indicator to show extra locations.**

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-locations true
```

**Set which locations to show.** Timezones are in the format `Continent/City_Name City Name`

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime locations "['America/Los_Angeles Los Angeles', 'America/New_York New York', 'Europe/London London', 'Europe/Paris Paris', 'Asia/Tokyo Tokyo']"
```

**To undo your changes**, you can simply hide the locations again.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-locations false
```

Comment: Great answer, better than accepted because it is native solution without 3-rd party installations.