# Impossible to change time

Tags: wingpanel, time

Here lies the issue : when I try to change the hour displayed by the wingpanel via the parameters, it does not take into account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add multiple timezones to Freya?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/how-can-i-add-multiple-timezones-to-freya)

Comment: No, it's not. The problem is that the time do not change when I change the timezone I'm in. It doesn't take it into account. No matter what I tried yet.

Comment: What have you tried? Why are you setting your time via command line and not via the settings option?

Comment: I might not express myself correctly : I try to change the setting via the menu, the GUI ! 
The window with the world-map, where you choose your timezone !