# How can I add multiple timezones to loki?

Tags: release-loki

[The solution for freya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/how-can-i-add-multiple-timezones-to-freya) no longer works as there is no `com.canonical.indicator`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new datetime indicator doesn't have this feature yet.

Comment: Bad news :( I really liked that feature a lot..